# How to re-read content of of file on form 1 from form 2?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

So here is my problem...

I have form 1, in which I am opening MS Access file which display the content into my multiline textbox on form 1. In form 2, I am adding an entry to the file. Now, how can I read new version of the file and display the content into my textbox on form 1?

What's the easy way of doing it?

I was thinking of somehow activating a button, button that reads and display the content of the file, on form 1 from form 2 just to re-read the file and display it again. But I'm not fully sure if that's possible...

What's the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FileSystemWatcher in Form1 to watch the Access file, every time when Form2 update that file, it will reload Form1.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

After you finish editting the file in form 2, you can raise an event that form 1 handled to reload the content. So you don't need to implement reload button in form 1. See the link to study How to implement Event in C#
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a trick ie

write your data loading code in a public function i.e.

```
public void ReadData()
{
 //your data logic here
}
```

while you create an instance of second form i.e data entry form

```
Frmdataentry frm=new Frmdataentry(); //say
frm.Tag=this; //store calling form reference
frm.Show();
```

on dataentry form whenever you update data (tables or anything)

write

```
//your data update finishes here
frmdataview f=(frmdataview)this.Tag; //retrieve calling form reference 
if(f!=null)
{
 f.ReadData();  //public method of frmdataview that loads/refreshes data
}
```

Comment: Nice approach. I'll try this later.